# Production and reporting database on the same server

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have our Production database and Reporting database on the same server. I am creating an analysis cube and can read data from any of the two databases. Both Production and Reporting databases are replicated through transactional replication, its a one way replication from production database to reporting database. The database is MS Sql Server 2008. My question is since both databases resides on the same server, and sharing resources from the same server how much difference it will make if I read data from Production database instead of Reporting database.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  What differences are you hoping to quantify?  When I hear "replicated", I tend to think its not truly a production db unless you have bi-directional replication on it, in which case I'd question why its on a reporting server if performance/contention is a concern.  You need to provide a lot more info before anyone will tackle this.

Comment: @JiggsJedi I have edited my question hope it will clarify what I want to ask?